# "to build meaningful relationships in important areas of my life"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Should I have said "of my life" or "in my life" in this sentence:

> to build meaningful relationships  in
>   important areas of my life

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a nitpicker, I must point out that your example is a phrase, not a sentence :)

Comment: @Jimi feel free to alter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Of" is the correct word there;  "In (qualifiers) of (item)" is the normal construction.  To use "in", you would lead in with "at":  "At (qualifiers) in (item)."  (To give a concrete and relevant example, your sentence fragment is using the phrase "important areas" as the qualifier for the main item, "my life".)

Often, "in/of" is used for broader, sometimes vague groupings, whereas "at/in" is always used for more specific things:  "in some parts of the world" vs. "at several points in the process."  Since your sentence uses the pretty broad and vague phrase "important areas", using the at/in combination would not be appropriate.

Another way to view it is that "in/of" is used to express containment, while "at/in" is used to express location.  Your life clearly contains several important areas, but they are not physical areas that you are trying to locate on a chart or diagram, so "in/of" is the appropriate construct.  On the other hand, if you are speaking of your life metaphorically as a timeline, you can certainly say something like "I was at a critical juncture in my life" to reference a specific, pinpointable moment.

Comment: So, I'm guessing, **at** could also work in this example? Then what would the difference be? btw what do you mean by "qualifiers of item"?

Comment: No, at wouldn't work in your example. It's somewhat hard to explain as I'm 'just' a native speaker, and as such know little about the technicalities of the language *per se*. I just know what sounds right! I'm afraid Hellion's answer is somewhat confusing, with its ()s and /s.

Answer (score 4):

Of my life is the correct usage.

'Of' means 'belonging to or connected with something or someone'. In this case the 'important areas' belong to 'my life'.

> This is the happiest day of my life.

'In' (in relation to 'my life') refers to something or someone 'within' your life, but separate from it:

> You are the most important person in my life.

You would never say:

> You are the most important person of my life.

Comment: To get the full credit, please explain why **of my life** is a correct usage

Answer (score 0):

Either is acceptable. "Of" is probably more idiomatic, but I don't know on what grounds the other repliers have asserted that "in" is less "correct".

In the BNC, "of" gets 5 hits, and "in" 0; but in Google, "of" gets 6.74 million and "in" 1.1 million.